# R: How to rearrange redundant values in columns so that there are less rows and more columns

Tags: r, genome

I currently have a table that looks like this:

[Picture 1- Current Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohjyW.png)

There are 3 sets of repeating segments of 83, 16, 24. I want to rearrange the table so that each of these values exist only once, instead of 3 times. This would add more columns on the right for each of the values in ColB.

Here is the desired table:

[Picture 2- Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zy6H.png)

Each of the values in the original ColA is only listed once now instead of 3 times. And then the original ColB values that corresponded with the redundant ColA values are organized into ColB1, ColB2, and ColB3.

I am wondering if anyone has any idea on how to go about rearranging the original table so that it becomes the desired table in the second picture? It's easy enough to rearrange now manually but I want to be able to deal with 1000s of values. I have tried pivot_wider and spread but haven't managed to make it work, and have not been able to find a solution on StackOverflow. If anyone has any advice on a direction to head in, that would be appreciated, and if anything is unclear in this question please let me know!

Also, in case anyone is wondering why I added the genome tag, it's because colA values are actually genome positions and colB values are allele frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with pivot_wider.

Here's what I did to replicate your pictures.  Note: I added a column "Allele" to designate the partitions.  Ideally this would come from your source dataset.

```
    # data
data <- tribble(
  ~ColA, ~ColB, ~Allele,
  "83", 0.5, "1",
  "16", 0.3, "1",
  "24", 0.2, "1",
  "83", 0.5, "2",
  "16", 0.1, "2",
  "24", 0.8, "2",
  "83", 0.6, "3",
  "16", 0.5, "3",
  "24", 0.6, "3",
)

# pivot to column based
new_data <- data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_prefix = "ColB", names_from = Allele, values_from = ColB)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help- this worked perfectly! I tried to upvote your comment but it doesn't show up because I don't have enough reputation points.